# How come Pikachu was able to defeat Geodude with a Thunderbolt?

Tags: pokemon

In "Showdown in Pewter City" Pikachu shocks Geodude once and it's defeated. Geodude is a Rock/Ground-type and shouldn't be vulnerable to Electric attacks. How come Pikachu defeated it so easily?

Comment: In all honesty,  weird that the accepted awnser is disproven by the simplest of Google searches seeing the entire statement about Geodude being pure rock is false :|

Answer (score 10):

Simple...Anime Logic, the Anime has broken the rules (in Ash his favor) more times then anyone should care to count.

But the explanation given is that Brock's father helped Ash "overcharge" his Pikachu to make him deal more damage. Later it is retroactively explained in **Tree's a Crowd**(AG007) that Pokémon can defuse electricity in the ground but when levitating like Geodude they can't diffuse it...

Best is not to use game logic in the series seeing they don't match in the slightest with the series making a lot of errors or outright retcons to make Ash win.

On a side note, Rock and Electric have no specials effect on each other. A Pure rock-type can get hit by an electric attack... Ground however is fully immune.

Answer (score 3):

Pikachu also defeats another Geodude in [*Pokemon Ruby and Sapphire: Nosepass's Secret Weapon*](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/AG016). The implication seems to be that while 'electric types' aren't particularly effective against 'rock types', the rock types aren't *immune* to their attacks.

Pikachu's Thunderbolt attack is a powerful attack and even an *ineffective* hit is sufficient to knock out a mid-level Pokémon, regardless of type.

Comment: Yet Geodude is part Ground type that is fully immune to electric attacks and therefor the attack should deal no damage how  powerful it might be. Also Electric attack's are NOT ineffective to rock types, this is a common misconception made seeing in the first generation all common rock types (so not the rare/unique fossil Pokémon) were also part ground and therefor immune.

Comment: @A.bakker - In the anime, it doesn't appear to be ineffective on the various occasions it's used. Are you conflating the game with the anime?

Comment: It is also stated that Ground types are fully immune in the anime, and other times they are not it seems to be a major inconsistency in the show with itself let alone the games they are supposedly based on.